# WCF web service hosted in IIS, create Fire and Forget method for non-.Net caller

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5, fire-and-forget

I have WCF web service hosted in IIS 7.5, .Net Framework 4.5.1.  I need a fire-and-forget method which is called by a non-.Net application (I cannot create a .Net proxy).

This is "true fire-and-forget."  The caller cares nothing about success or failure.

Is it as simple as wrapping all of the code in Task.Run()?  Is this sufficient?

```
[OperationContract]
public void FireAndForget(string stuffToSave)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try 
        {
            LongRunningProcess.Save(stuffToSave);
        {
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
        }
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: I think you even don't need to do this, because the client can call your service and don't wait for any response. But for clients that may wait for a response to see if the server received their request, you can simply use `Task.Run(() => { /*codes here*/ });`

Comment: You may consider using **IsOneWay=true** property in your **OperationContract** [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]. This is usual way to achieve what you need without changing business logic code and wrapping it with the task. Not sure how it would be handled by non .NEt client, but you can check it. With **Task** approach you have pretty obvious drawback - to every call, which consumes a thread, you add one more call, which increases the usage of thread pool twice.